# Is it possible to pass raw video frame TO a browser?

Tags: html, video, browser, udp, webrtc

*Is possible to pipe raw video frames to a browser/website? For instance the decoding could be done locally in Gstreamer, and then that could be forwarded somehow to a browser.*

**EDIT:
I realize that my description was a bit shaky. The use case I would like to have is to send encoded video to someone, decode it on their computer, do some advance filtering that cannot be done in the browser, and then pipe the frames to the browser. Obviously re-encoding it would just be a waste of time and energy.**

All that I can find is ppl saying that video frames can be grabbed FROM a browser, no-one seems to be interested to SENT TO a browser. The horrible option could be to use webrtc and to re-encode the frames into VP8 and then to send it to the browser.

So my final question is whether it is possible to write to the rendering pipeline of a browser? I know next to nothing about web programming, I usually just deal with images and video. 
Thank you for your support :)

PS: forgive my lack of knowledge, is it possible to have a client on someone's computer, writting to a local tcp port, and to access that tcp port from a website in the browser? (potentially asking the user to allow the connection?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  Since you're running a local GStreamer pipeline, you might look into this project:  https://github.com/Samsung/ChromiumGStreamerBackend  Basically, they're using GStreamer as the native renderer in-browser.

Aside from that, you can create a browser extension which executes an application and gets data from Gstreamer, to shuffle to your application.  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

If you don't want to make an extension, you can instead create a small Web Socket server.

Either way, you can write the raw pixel data to a Canvas... no need to re-encode/decode the video.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Brad, your comment is quite helpful. I will read over these links. Do you know which of these options would allow to treat the frames in the GPU? That is why I am looking into this.

Comment: I wanted to upvote this answer, but I don't have enough reputation points, thanks though!